# CSS-tags added using Display suite on products disappears

Tags: commerce

Using Display Suite to format output of entity product from Drupal Commerce. HTML- and CSS-tags added by "Expert" formatting tend to disappear when products are viewed using display-nodes. In this case its a image-field with n-number of images that I'm trying to display in a horizontal row instead of stack them vertical. I'm using fancybox as display widget and want to change the behaivor with "float: left; position: relative;". Drupal 7.

The dialog for entering the extra tags are displayed both in product-type view and node-type view when administer fields. It does not matter if I do the formatting at product-type-level or node-type.

When adding the same formatting with a non commerce node-type it works as I suppose it should.

Are there a better way to accomplish horizontal rows with thumnails and displaying full size-pictures using fanzybox when presenting commerce products?

I have been using lightbox2, but it seems to be a bug when combining it with Drupal Commerce.

Answer (score 0):

I am not trying to do any grid nor gallery, but have had success with Colorbox.
http://drupal.org/node/1230232 for info on enabling it.